# Getting when a text file is edited by another program

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-files

So I have a python script (let's call it `file_1.py`) that overwrites the content of a text file with new content, and it works just fine. I have another python script (`file_2.py`) that reads the file and performs actions on the data in the file. With `file_2.py` I've been trying to get when the text file is edited by `file_1.py` and then do some stuff with the new data as soon as it's added. I looked into the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) but I couldn't really figure out how to use it across different files. Here's what I have so far:
`file_1.py:`

```
with open('text_file.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(assemble(''.join(data))) # you can ignore what assemble does, this part already works.
```

`file_2.py:`

```
while True:
    f = open('text_file.txt','r')
    data = f.read()
    function(data)
    f.close()
```

I thought that since I close and reopen the file every loop, the data in the file would be updated. However, it appears I was wrong, as the data remains the same even though the file was updated. 
So how can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you always overwiting the data in the first file, with the same data?
I mean, instead of appending or actually changing the data over time?

I see it working here when I change

```
with open('text_file.txt','wt') as f:
```

to

```
with open('text_file.txt','at') as f:
```

and I append some data. `'w'` will overwrite and if data doesn't change you will see the same data over and over.

Edit:

Another possibility (as discussed in the comments to OP self-answer) is the need to use `f.flush()` after writing to the file. Despite the buffers being written to disk automatically when closing a file (or leaving a `with` block), that write can take a moment, and if the file is read again before that moment, the updates will not be there (yet). To remove that uncertainty call flush after updating, wich forces the disk write.

If you sleep your reading code for enough time between readings (that is the reads are slow enough), the manual flush might not be needed. But if in doubt, or to do it the simple way and be sure, just use `flush()`.

Comment: I am completely overwriting the file every time. 100% new data.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it looks like I've solved my problem. According to [this website](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_flush.htm), it says:

> Python automatically flushes the files when closing them. But you may want to flush the data before closing any file.

Since the "automatic flushing" thing wasn't working, I tried to manually flush the I/O using `file.flush()`, and it worked. I call that function every time right write to the file in `file_1.py`.

EDIT: It seems that when `time.sleep()` is called between readings of the file, it interferes and you have to manually flush the buffer.

Comment: Glad you solved it. Actually I added a `flush()` but it was working even without the `flush`, wich refrain me from saying right away use flush(). That was because I used sleep(0.2) for the while to be able to see the file content scrolling before my eyes. That lead me into thinking that maybe your while was reading too fast for you to see the change (immediately). It happens the answer was the simple one... but I still recommend using sleep. Why reading the file at such high speed?

Comment: well actually in the function call I have in my loop there was a call of `time.sleep()`, so maybe that had something to do with it.

Comment: what happens is that if you close the file manually, or by leaving a with block, the updates will be written, but it can take a while to happen. That is why I happen to read the udates successfully even without flush. Because I spent a larger amount of time with sleep() before reading again, than the required time for that writing to take effect. By using flush() you force the file buffers to write to the disk at that moment, eliminating that uncertainty.

Comment: what exactly did you consider to be the proper answer, my answer or my comment about "what happens". If it was the comment and the use of `flush()`  maybe I should edit the answer to reflect that.

Comment: yeah it was the comment

Comment: ok then, just edited for other readers to understand solely by reading the answer. I felt it wasn't quite right for an accepted answer.