# How to empty buffer without restarting Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python **3.6.3**.

A problem remains in my script, which is fully operational.

Main modules are ***pandas*** and ***xslxwriter*** (with ***easygui*** for GUI).

From a single master file (Excel 2010), this script can generate dozens of Excel files (with ***xlsxwriter***), each of them can contain hundreds of columns of data (depending of parameters of the master file).

Indentation, logic and results are OK.

But the last Excel file is not committed to disk, and I have to restart Python to get it.

For example, if one run produces 100 files, only 99 will be written on disk. The last one is calculated, but not visible.

If Python is not restarted, this file is written to disk at the beginning of a next run of the script.

I identified maybe a ***flush*** problem, and tried some solutions, but this problem still remains.

Are there some tricks to force the buffer?  I am not allowed to modify the environment variables on my professional computer.

Thank you for your help and your time :)

Comment: Show code, but probably you aren't closing the file properly.

Comment: Do you mean that a workbook,close is missing?

Comment: I mean you've shown no code, but if you open a file, you need to close the file to flush it to disk properly.  Once you open a file, though, it is generally visible, just empty.  Create a [mcve] of the problem.

Comment: For flush see the related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47488016/getting-when-a-text-file-is-edited-by-another-program/47488321), including also the OP self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you **Mark Tolonen**

You were right : the file was not closed properly, and it was because I made a mistake.

My code was a bit difficult to summarize, and I could not post a *résumé* of my script.

First, a keyword ***continue*** (for the main loop) was bad-indented and I replaced it at the right place.

But just before this keyword, I was closing the ***xlsxwriter*** file with: **workbook.close** (only one in the script exists for the main loop).

**But this was not mentioned as an error at run-time**.

Each ***xlsxwriter*** file was committed to disk except the last one, as mentioned in my question above.

I then reviewed the documentation at https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html, and I noticed that parenthesis were missing when worbook is closed.

After correction by adding the missing parenthesis: ***workbook.close*()**, all is fine now :)

I would like to share this information, because some may have meet the same problem.

Than you also to  **progmatico** for your information on ***flush*** properties.

Greetings from **Paris, France** :)

Comment: This question can be closed, thank you :)